# Java Lost my Dice on the Board

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am trying to write a monopoly game. Below you are gonna see my games code. First I made the game and I made tokens walk through the board. Then I add dice. I saw dice on my board. Then I want to add a Roll Dice button when I roll the dice my tokens are moving but I can no longer see my dice. Now, still I cannot see tried everything I know, couldn't find anything in the web. Anyone can help? If you need any more classes from my project just comment it and I will add it in a min.

```
public class Game {
Player p1;
Player p2;
int posx = 619;
int posy = 619;
int posx1 = 619;
int posy1 = 619;
int d1;
int d2;
int turn;
Card[] cards;

public Game(JTextArea textArea, JButton btnRollDice) {
    cards = new Card[40];
    initCards();
    p1 = new Player("Onurcan", 1);
    p2 = new Player("Batoç", 2);
    play(textArea, btnRollDice);

}

public void play(JTextArea textArea, JButton button) {
    Game g = this;
    turn = p1.getPnumber();
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Dice d = new Dice();
            d1 = d.getDice1();
            d2 = d.getDice2();
            if (turn == p1.getPnumber()) {
                textArea.append(p1.getPname() + "'s dice is " + d.getDice()
                        + "\n");
                Round r = new Round(p1, d, g);
                r.changePosition(p1, d, g);
                textArea.append(p1.getPname() + " welcome to "
                        + g.getCards()[p1.getPosition()].getName() + "\n");
                textArea.append(p1.getPname() + " your balance is "
                        + p1.getBalance() + "\n");
                turn = p2.getPnumber();
            } else if (turn == p2.getPnumber()) {
                textArea.append(p2.getPname() + "'s dice is " + d.getDice()
                        + "\n");
                Round r = new Round(p2, d, g);
                r.changePosition(p2, d, g);
                textArea.append(p2.getPname() + " welcome to "
                        + g.getCards()[p2.getPosition()].getName() + "\n");
                textArea.append(p2.getPname() + " your balance is "
                        + p2.getBalance() + "\n");
                turn = p1.getPnumber();
            }
        }
    });
}

public class Board extends JPanel {
private ImageIcon image;
private JLabel label;
private JLabel dlabel;
private JLabel dlabel2;

public Board(Game g) {
    setLayout(null);
    image = new ImageIcon("board.jpg");
    label = new JLabel(image);
    label.setSize(700, 700);
    dlabel2 = displayDice(g, g.getD2());
    dlabel2.setSize(50, 50);
    dlabel2.setLocation(351, 350);

    dlabel = displayDice(g, g.getD1());
    dlabel.setSize(50, 50);
    dlabel.setLocation(299, 350);
    g.getP1().getToken().setSize(24, 24);
    g.getP1().getToken().setLocation(g.getPosx(), g.getPosy());
    add(g.getP1().getToken());
    g.getP2().getToken().setSize(24, 24);
    g.getP2().getToken().setLocation(g.getPosx1(), g.getPosy1());
    add(g.getP2().getToken());
    add(dlabel);
    add(dlabel2);
    add(label);
}

public JLabel displayDice(Game g, int d) {
    image = new ImageIcon("dice"+d+".jpg");
    dlabel = new JLabel(image);
    return dlabel;
}
```

}

```
public class Token extends JPanel {
ImageIcon image;
JLabel token;

public Token(int pnumber) {
    if (pnumber == 1) {
        image = new ImageIcon("hat.png");
        token = new JLabel(image);
    }
    if (pnumber == 2) {
        image = new ImageIcon("shoe.jpeg");
        token = new JLabel(image);
    }
    add(token);
}
```

}

```
public class Dice {
int dice;
int dice1;
int dice2;

public Dice() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Random rand2 = new Random();
    dice1 = rand.nextInt(6);
    dice2 = rand2.nextInt(6);
    dice1++;
    dice2++;
    dice = dice1 + dice2;
}

public int getDice() {
    return dice;
}

public int getDice1() {
    return dice1;
}

public int getDice2() {
    return dice2;
}
```

}

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Player {
    String pname;
    int balance;
    int pnumber;
    int position;
    JPanel token;

public Player(String name, int p) {
    pname = name;
    balance = 1500;
    position = 0;
    pnumber = p;
    token = new Token(pnumber);
}

public JPanel getToken() {
    return token;
}

public int getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(int balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}

public int getPnumber() {
    return pnumber;
}

public String getPname() {
    return pname;
}
```

}

```
public class Card {
String name;
int price;
int rent;
int rent1;
int rent2;
int rent3;
int rent4;
int renth;
String colorgroup;

public Card(String n, int p, int r, int r1, int r2, int r3, int r4, int rh, String cg) {
    name = n;
    price = p;
    rent = r;
    rent1 = r1;
    rent2 = r2;
    rent3 = r3;
    rent4 = r4;
    renth = rh;
    colorgroup = cg;
}

public Card(String n, String cg) {
    name = n;
    colorgroup = cg;
}

public Card(String n, int p, String cg) {
    name = n; 
    price = p;
    colorgroup = cg;
}

public Card(String n, int p, int r, int r1, int r2, int r3, String cg) {
    name = n;
    price = p;
    rent = r;
    rent1 = r1;
    rent2 = r2;
    rent3 = r3;
    colorgroup = cg;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public int getRent() {
    return rent;
}

public int getRent1() {
    return rent1;
}

public int getRent2() {
    return rent2;
}

public int getRent3() {
    return rent3;
}

public int getRent4() {
    return rent4;
}

public int getRenth() {
    return renth;
}

public String getColorgroup() {
    return colorgroup;
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you creating a new `Dice` on every button click ?

Comment: Because I am rolling dice. What do u suggest instead?

Comment: Your code is not **runnable**.  We're missing classes like Player and Card that could be important to solving your problem.  Help us help you by reducing your code down to the smallest possible Java application that **executes**.  I'm not going through hundreds of lines of code unless I can run the code and see what happens.

Comment: OK. I added all mate Can anyone please help me. Show me a little way?

Comment: Have only one Dice and roll it every time you need a value! `Dice d = new Dice();`... `int value = d.roll()`... A dice is an object, so you don't have to create a new dice every time you need values! Anyway, we can't help you more because there is missing parts in your code...

Comment: I added the missing parts. Can you take a look?